# Pandas: how to merge horizontally multiple CSV (key,value) files and name `value` columns in the resulting DF using filenames

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have 16 different csv files in one directory and I am trying to load them into one pandas dataframe. Each file has `datetime` and `float64` columns. All CSV files do not have column headers. Directory

```
location = os.path.join(base_dir, "DirectoryName")
symbols = os.listdir(location)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
for symbol in symbols:
    location = os.path.join(base_dir, "DirectoryName", symbol)
    df_temp = pd.read_csv(location, index_col=0, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True, na_values=['nan'])
    df_temp.dropna()
    df_temp.index = df_temp.index.normalize()
    df_temp = normalize_data(df_temp)
    df = df.join(df_temp)
```

The problem that I have now is the final dataframe `df` that has `datetime` as it's index but it's corresponding row values as column names and the first row is filled with `NaN`

Here is the snapshot
[image: notice row values for 2015-04-02]

I have to remove the first row of `df`, but that won't help much while doing other operations as some data will be missing. I couldn't rename the column header as it is different for each file and I know only how to change that statically.

Comment: how are you going to merge/join all your CSV files into single DF if your columns `is different for each file`? Do you want to merge them horizontally?

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you would post a link to one/two of your CSV files or post here a small data sample in text form...

Comment: All the files have first column in common which i am using as an index. Here is the link to the files @MaxU 
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2I8HUL0xRSWVlZNb1hHckRwRVE&usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've downloaded just the following files:

```
['hash_rate.csv',
 'difficulty.csv',
 'cost_per_tx.csv',
 'block_size.csv',
 'avg_block_size.csv']
```

That's why you will see just a corresponding part of your data in the resulting DF.

Please find comments in the code.

Code:

```
import os
import glob
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

def read_files(filelist):
    # `dfs` - will contain a list of DFs
    # that will be concatenated later on
    dfs = []
    for fn in filelist:
        # parse column name from filename
        col = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(fn)[-1])[0]
        # read individual CSV (as data blocks from defaultdict) into temp DF
        # and add this temporary DF into `dfs` list
        dfs.append(pd.read_csv(
                        fn,
                        parse_dates=[0],
                        header=None,
                        index_col='date',
                        names=['date', col]
                   )
        )
    # return concatenated horizontally (axis=1) DF
    return pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

def main():
    data_files_mask = r'D:\temp\.data\36827502\*.csv'
    df = read_files(glob.glob(data_files_mask))
    print(df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
                     block_size     hash_rate  avg_block_size  cost_per_tx  \
date
2015-01-05 18:15:05     34469.0  3.479099e+08        0.375637     8.185000
2015-01-06 18:15:05     36219.0  3.323940e+08        0.477130     6.598278
2015-01-07 18:15:05     38212.0  3.560892e+08        0.624724     6.232809
2015-01-08 18:15:05     40943.0  4.261981e+08        0.754424     7.113695
2015-01-09 18:15:05     43021.0  4.099610e+08        0.515467     6.199964
2015-01-10 18:15:05     45487.0  4.655484e+08        0.451940     6.821970
2015-01-11 18:15:05     47963.0  4.920513e+08        0.535354     7.958116
2015-01-12 18:15:05     50594.0  6.940933e+08        0.536199     9.415383
2015-02-04 18:15:05     32832.0  3.413843e+08        0.421406     8.054181
2015-02-05 18:15:05     34523.0  3.479099e+08        0.373642     8.958115

                       difficulty
date
2015-01-05 18:15:05  4.761056e+10
2015-01-06 18:15:05  4.880749e+10
2015-01-07 18:15:05  4.940201e+10
2015-01-08 18:15:05  5.227830e+10
2015-01-09 18:15:05  5.425663e+10
2015-01-10 18:15:05  6.081322e+10
2015-01-11 18:15:05  6.225398e+10
2015-01-12 18:15:05  7.272278e+10
2015-02-04 18:15:05  4.671755e+10
2015-02-05 18:15:05  4.761056e+10
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider explicitly defining columns with [read_csv's](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) `names` argument, using the very file name, `symbol` in the loop (of course replacing the `.csv` extension):

```
for symbol in symbols:
    ...
    df_temp = pd.read_csv(location, 
                          index_col=0, 
                          parse_dates=True, 
                          dayfirst=True, 
                          na_values=['nan'],
                          header=None,
                          names=['date', symbol.replace('.csv', '')])
```